# add .SendKeys to an existing macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that would help me with printing a document from Excel.
It has a couple dialogue questions for adding serial number sequence and number of copies.

Unfortunately, it doesn't open the Print dialogue, where I can select a printer and it's preferences.
The code would just immediately print to my default printer.

I need to add some custom features like 2-side printing and stapling in the top left corner.
For that purpose I want to use **.Sendkeys**

I tried adding the string **Application.SendKeys "%fpr"** (my printer preferences dialogue) here and there inside the code to no avail.

Please help inserting the sting.

Alternatively - maybe there is a command for .PrintOut that I could add for 2-side printing and a staple finish?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xCount As Variant
    Dim xJAC As Variant
    Dim xID As Variant
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.SendKeys "%fpr"
LInput:
    xJAC = Application.InputBox("Please enter the job number (Leave Out JAC):", "")
    xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:", "")
    xID = Application.InputBox("Please enter the Starting ID of the product:", "")
    If TypeName(xJAC) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If TypeName(xID) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Or (xID < 1) Or (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xID)) Then
        MsgBox "error entered, please enter again", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo LInput
        
    Else
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For c = 0 To xCount - 1
                ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Value = "JAC" & xJAC
                ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Value = xID + c
                ActiveSheet.PrintOut
            Next
        ActiveSheet.Range("E2").ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Range("G2").ClearContents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Using SendKeys is very unreliable and has a very high probability that it sometimes works correctly and sometimes fails. Also any update of Excel's user interface can crash your code easily. • Also `On Error Resume Next` hides all your error messages and therefore you cannot see what is going wrong. You need to remove that line and fix your errors.

Comment: I recommend to install the same printer a second time and in this printer make these properties like 2-side printing and a staple finish the default. Then let Excel print on this printer via VBA. That is how I do it and it works reliable.

Comment: that's a good idea - but at which point should I interrupt the above code. See, after clicking the macro button, it just asks the # of copies and prints immediately. At least, I wish to be able to select a printer - which part of the code needs to be deleted/edited for the "Print" window. Thanks

Comment: There are tons of information about how to print on a specific printer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63790613/specify-printer-when-printing-files just give it a try.